# Trouble with supervisor reread?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I use **NGINX+DJANGO+GUNICORN+SUPERVISOR** virtualenv with python3.6.
I created `mysite.conf` at `/etc/supervisor/conf.d`

```
[program:mysite]
command = /home/split/mysite/gunicorn_start.bash                  ; Command to start app
user = split                                                ; User to run as
stdout_logfile = /home/split/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log   ; Where to write log messages
redirect_stderr = true                                       ; Save stderr in the same log
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8              ; Set UTF-8 as default encoding
```

After that I tried to reread supervisor

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
```

And got

```
error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py line: 228
```

Comment: It tries to restart supervisor with python2.7, did you activate your virtualenv?

Comment: (venv) split@ubuntu:~$ python --version
Python 3.6.3
(venv) split@ubuntu:~$ sudo supervisorctl reread
error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py line: 228

Comment: Sudo executes the command as root, root hasn't activated virtualenv